# Non-volatile storage system made up of logic gates

Tags: logic-gates, data-storage

So, I don't want all my data blown away every time I turn off my system, so how would I create a storage system that doesn't use batteries but also keeps the data that I have stored?

Comment: "*Non-volatile memory*" is the term.

Answer (score 1):

As Houston Fortney says in a comment, you need a physical phenomenon which exhibits memory. Furthermore it must be electrically controllable, ideally reversible or somehow resettable, and electrically detectable. And presumably it has to be accessible for home construction.

A latching relay has been mentioned - for a small number of bits, a small number of relays is viable.

Other options :

1. Magnetisable ferrite cores. You can occasionally buy surplus "planes" of [core memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) left over from 1960's computers. The electronics to support these is feasible in discrete transistors (probably needs inappropriate voltages for common ICs) but definitely not an exercise for the faint-hearted.
2. An E-Ink display from something like an Amazon Kindle, and a camera, mounted in a frame.
3. A variation on this : a matrix of high-power SMD resistors on a PCB under thermal printer paper, and a camera. The electronics to power the resistors to make dark spots on the paper will be much easier than driving the E-Ink display if you insist on doing it yourself. To clear the memory, simply replace the paper.
4. A network of fuses or fragile components which you can destroy by overcurrent, or read by applying lower current. These used to be available as ["fusible link PROMs"](http://ygg-it.tripod.com/id3.html) in the 74 series TTL logic family but in principle you could easily make your own with a [matrix of short thin wires](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/rom3.htm), and high current row and column drivers. Resetting a bit requires soldering though. Unless you make it from a matrix of 3V mini lamp bulbs, which you "read" at 3V and "program" at 6V, in which case all you need to do is replace all the bulbs in a row to reset that byte.
5. Model control servos or stepper motors driving potentiometers or rotary switches. If you can control position to about 1% accuracy you may get 6 or 7 bits from a potentiometer, or 4 bits (reliably!) from a hex coded switch.

By now I expect you're taking another look at that non-volatile memory...

Answer (score 0):

Use a memory IC like [this one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/I2C%20Serial%20EE%20Family%20Data%20Sheet%2021930C.pdf). You will need a microcontroller to read/write it. Another option is to select a microcontroller with integrated memory that meets your needs. If your application does not otherwise need a micro, you can use a very small/cheap one.

If you only need one or a few bits, consider a latching relay like [this little guy](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TQ2SA-L2-24V/255-1772-5-ND/570908).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't have any basic schematics, or complex, I just needed a basic idea of a design.

Comment: You can't construct nonvolatile memory from standard logic gates. You need a physical phenomenon which exhibits memory. The most basic way to include nonvolatile memory into a circuit is a small 8 pin micro. Unless you only need one bit. In that case you can use a latching relay. How many bits do you want?

Comment: 1 bit, so what physical phenomena could I use other than, dun dun dun Optical?

Comment: @EnderScythe  This is not unlike [changing a tire with a soup ladle](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/811/7036).  Why do you need non-volatile memory?  Why don't existing non-volatile memories fit your requirements?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: For one bit a latching relay is a reasonable option. Personally I'd still go for a micro for reasons of long term reliability.

Comment: Latching relay?

Comment: Yeah, it keeps it's position even after you stop powering the coil. See my edits for an example.